# Getting org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException only for Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am tring to find a button in a webpage using find elements, the page can contain one of the below button ID's.

`driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'topBtn')]"))
 driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'WSMplasticTop')]"))
 driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'bottomApplyBtn')]"))`

The above code is working as expected when i use the Firefox Driver, where as getting the below error when i run in Chrome Driver.

`org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[contains(@id='bottomApplyBtn')] because of the following error: 
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[contains(@id='bottomApplyBtn')]' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Just wanted to know whether i have done any mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
'//*[contains(@id,'bottomApplyBtn')]'
```

instead of

```
'//*[contains(@id='bottomApplyBtn')]'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `contains` method in your `XPath` expression, you basically are using an inbuilt `method` to find the element.

This method takes 2 parameters.

1. First the tag you in which you want to search.
2. Second is the actual text value which you are looking for inside the above tag.

Basically you have to call the method with 2 parameters and that 2 parameters should be `comma` separated.

So `//*[contains(@id='bottomApplyBtn')]` is wrong you should instead remove this `=` sign.

```
//*[contains(@id, 'bottomApplyBtn')]
              |_______|____________________ Parameter 1
                      |__________________________________Parameter 2
```

Hope it helps!